# Call action when detecting sound? (Radio Streaming)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, streaming, avplayer

I've been programming in Xcode for a total of three months and I'm stuck with this small problem:

At the moment I'm building a radio-streaming app with *AVPlayer* where you can choose from a bunch of different radiostations in a *UICollectionView*. When you select a station, a subView appears which darkens the *UICollectionView* and show a loading-view with the name of the station and an *ActivityIndicator*. So far so good.

The problem is I don't know how to get rid of the view once it has begun playing. Right now I'm temporarily closing it down manually by touching the view, but of course I want this to happen automatically when the app detects the sound.

**Where should I place my dismiss-method to close the subView when radio starts playing/finish loading?**

Screenshot of subView:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49270819/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2026%20feb%202013%2023.54.04.png

Thank you!

Comment: `[mySubView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Thanks Till. Though I already figured out how to get rid of my subView. The problem is I don't know where to place this action to make it disappear when a radiostation starts playing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to start sound monitoring:

#pragma mark - AudioStuff

```
double lowPassResultAudio;
-(void) initAudioRecorder {
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setDelegate: self];
    NSError *audioSessionError;
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&audioSessionError];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &audioSessionError];

    NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // We can use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 (4:1 compression) or kAudioFormatLinearPCM for nocompression
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    // We can use 44100, 32000, 24000, 16000 or 12000 depending on sound quality
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    // We can use 2(if using additional h/w) or 1 (iPhone only has one microphone)
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    //initiate recorder
    inputAudioUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:inputAudioUrl settings:recordSetting error:&error];
    if(recorder){
        //setting to speaker for appropritae recording
        UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                                 sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

        //for monitoring with same recorder
        [recorder record];

        [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] interval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(monitorAudioController:) userInfo:,mil repeats:YES]

    } else
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

Now if sound value surpass a limit i.e. some near sound is playing, then remove your View.

```
//monitor audion with same recorder
-(void) monitorAudioController: (NSTimer *) timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];
    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel_ = pow(10, (ALPHA * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
//    double lowpassMultiplier = (lowPassResultAudio > 0.2f) ? 0.2f : lowPassResultAudio;
    double AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD = 0.7;
    lowPassResultAudio = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel_ + (1.0 - ALPHA) * AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD;

   // NSLog(@"peakPowerForChannel_=%lf, lowpassMultiplier = %lf, lowPassResultAudio = %lf", peakPowerForChannel_, AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD, lowPassResultAudio);
    if (lowPassResultAudio >= AUDIOMONITOR_THRESHOLD) {
           //remove here
           //invalidate timer
           //stop recorder monitoring
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response rptwsthi! I get the logic, but I have some problems trying to implement this. My main errors are: kAppDelegate.shouldRecordAudio(property not found), ccTime(expected type) and lowPassResultAudio(undeclared identifier). Could you explain these?

Comment: I have update the code for that those were some of global variable and some copy paste errors. :)

Comment: 'UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                                sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);'

Comment: I'm getting there! I also looked in to a tutorial about detecting sound trough the mic, and it appeared quite similar except for it should detect the phones sounds. This code above is giving me

 **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**. 
"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386"